# how can i unselect the custom option in magento?

Tags: magento

I have added custom option to a product.I am using following java script code for the selecting the custom option.

> $('options_optionId_Value').click();

By this i am able to select he custom option and price box is also reload by this. But i want to give a button,if user clicks on it,specific custom option should be removed and the price box should be reload.
For this i try to pass 0,none,false in the script but nothing is happen.Please give some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your select box, make first option as `Click here to select` (value="") or something like that. Check `onchange` of select if the value is blank then reload the price box. And if the value is not blank, reduce the price of that item.

Comment: yes, you are right actually i apologies,i should write clearly.I am editing the question.

Comment: $('#select_box_id_here').change(function() { alert('change event called..'); });

Comment: you can get the value of select dropdown by.. $('#select_box_id_here').val();